# How to hide the Side Bar in Blogger's Contempo template?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

Here's my [Blog](https://sushritpasupuleti.blogspot.com), I'd like to leave the side bar hidden by default, with an option to display it using the hamburger menu button. The thing is, it works at a few resolutions, and for some it plain doesn't.

As far as I can see, at resolutions below 1440p it's fine, above that the side bar is permanent, with no hide option.

Comment: Hi. Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Agree with @PIIANTOM
Please explain your issue in detail. For eg: for which resolutions it isn't working? or something else which we can use to resolve your issue.